# Is there a way to create a 2D bar chart using axlsx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

Currently there is only the `Axlsx::Bar3DChart`.
I was wondering if there was a 2D version of this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: I mean, is there an option wherein I can make it to look 2D?